# Kotlin is not working in vs code i have tried all things but nothing works

Tags: java, kotlin, visual-studio-code

```
PS C:\Users\Aaryan> kotlin -version
'java' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
PS C:\Users\Aaryan> cd "c:\Users\Aaryan\Desktop\kotlin\" ; if ($?) { kotlinc MainActivity.kt -include-runtime -d MainActivity.jar } ; if ($?) { java -jar MainActivity.jar }
'java' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I have installed java and change enviroment variables but it is not working

Comment: have you updated `PATH` environment variable to include path to java executable? Have you set `JAVA_HOME`?

Comment: yes i do  it....

Comment: Type `java -version` and `where java` in PowerShell or Command Prompt, can you get the right output?